# Given X and Y are independent ~N(0,1), what is the distribution of $ Z=X^2 + Y^2 $

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, data-transformation, joint-distribution, jacobian

Our joint pdf is $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}} e^\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$

Now we let $ U = X^2 + Y^2 $ and $ V = Y$, we can then get our Jacobian as $ J = \frac{1}{\sqrt{u-v^2}} $

Since this transformation isnt one to one on this range, we need to divide into to ranges $S_{1} = (-∞,0]  $ and $ S_{2} = (0, ∞) $

Thus I get $f(u,v) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{u-v^2}}(\frac{1}{2π}e^\frac{-u}{2})  $

This seems wrong, for some reason. Please tell me if this is incorrect thus far.

Comment: Use polar coordinates if you want to do this by change of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, it's [Chi squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with two degree of freedoms. The one you've found is the joint PDF of $U$ and $V$. You need to marginalize it to obtain $f_U(u)$:
$$f_U(u)=\int_{-\sqrt u}^\sqrt u \frac{1}{\sqrt{u-v^2}}\frac{e^{-u/2}}{2\pi}dv=\frac{e^{-u/2}}{2\pi}\overbrace{\int_{-\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt u}\frac{1}{u-v^2}dv}^\pi=\frac{1}{2}e^{-u/2}$$
where $u\geq 0$. This is at the same time an exponential RV with $\lambda=1/2$, and Chi-Squared RV with $k=2$.

Comment: thank you, this showed me my range was wrong for my marginal. appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, this should have chi-square distribution with 2 degrees of freedom.  If X and Y are standard normal, then this should follow from the definition of the chi square distribution. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Properties).